# Import of .bak file failed in plesk

Tags: database, ssms, hosting, plesk-onyx

I am trying to upload .bak file which i created in MS SQL like this:
http://prntscr.com/kz4jt5
and when i try upload it on plesk i got this error:
http://prntscr.com/kz4k00
This is version i picked for this database:
http://prntscr.com/kz4kbz
and this is version that is instaled on plesk: 
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)

I dont know what to do anymore, I contacted my hosting provider but he didnt solve my problem.

Comment: and hosting provider can not install Microsoft SQL 2017(it can be installed via plesk installer) ? or did you try to Dump the database in script format as it described at https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006604453

Comment: I didnt ask them to install version 2017, but i saw that article about scripts and i will try it. I dont know why my database dont act like its version 2014 if i choise that in options